# Please tell how to stop the category from showing up on posts

Tags: categories, loop, post-meta, content

Please tell me how to remove the category hence, it does not show up on posts.
my content.php file is given below...which contains the code for showing up meta.
but I am not able to figure out the file...please help

```
<?php
/**
 * Template part for displaying posts
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
 *
 * @package Magazine 7
 */

?>


<?php if (is_singular()) : ?>
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php
    the_content(sprintf(
        wp_kses(
        /* translators: %s: Name of current post. Only visible to screen readers */
            __('Continue reading<span class="screen-reader-text"> "%s"</span>', 'magazine-7'),
            array(
                'span' => array(
                    'class' => array(),
                ),
            )
        ),
        get_the_title()
    )); ?>
    <?PHP if (is_single()): ?>
        <div class="post-item-metadata entry-meta">
            <?php magazine_7_post_item_tag(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php
    the_post_navigation( array(
        'prev_text'                  => __( '<span class="em-post-navigation">Previous</span> %title', 'magazine-7' ),
        'next_text'                  => __( '<span class="em-post-navigation">Next</span> %title', 'magazine-7' ),
        'in_same_term'               => true,
       'taxonomy'                   => __( 'category', 'magazine-7' ),
        'screen_reader_text' => __( 'Continue Reading', 'magazine-7' ),
    ) );
    ?>
    <?php wp_link_pages(array(
        'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__('Pages:', 'magazine-7'),
        'after' => '</div>',
    ));
    ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

" 
                 data-mh="archive-layout-grid">
            
        
        
            " >

Answer (score 0):

Maybe commenting out that `magazine_7_post_item_tag()` call?